# Get sublists from list

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I am trying to write cross-validation code, and need to iterate through a set and split training and testing data. I am trying to split it in the following fashion, but the code does not compile

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]])
n_folds = 3

for n in range(n_folds):
    test_fold = X[n]
    train_folds = X[x for x in range(n_folds) if x != n]
    print train_folds, test_fold
```

Expected output

```
[3,4,5,6], [1,2]
[1,2,5,6], [3,4]
[1,2,3,4], [5,6]
```

Is there a way I can implement this?

Comment: At 1.6k+ rep you should know that you should be sharing the error you get.

Answer (score 3):

Add extra brackets:

```
X[[x for x in range(n_folds) if x != n]]
```

The inner brackets create a list (comprehension), the outer ones tells numpy to use that list for advanced indexing.